# Lower frattini subgroup

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Define $\Phi_{-}(G)$ as the subgroup of $G$ generated by all the minimal subgroups of $G$ (a minimal subgroup of $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ of prime order).

It is easy to check that the subgroup $\Phi_{-}(G)$ is normal in $G$. I think that the quotient group $G/\Phi_{-}(G)$ is nilpotent but I don't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 7):

The smallest counterexample is the dicyclic group of order $36$: $G=C_9\rtimes C_4$, with the generator of $C_4$ acting by inversion on $C_9$.

In this case, $\Phi_{-}(G)\cong C_6$, while $G/\Phi_{-}(G)\cong S_3$.